# Why can't I run this OOP code in my PyCharm IDE?

Tags: python, oop

I am new to OOP in python. I have issues calling my class methods in my PyCharm IDE.

Example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.previous = None
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
 
 
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.start_node = None
        self.last_node = None
 
    def append(self, data):
        if self.last_node is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
            self.last_node = self.head
       
        else:
            new_node = Node(data)
            self.last_node.next = new_node
            new_node.previous = self.last_node
            new_node.next = None
            self.last_node = new_node
 
    def display(self, Type):
        if Type == 'Left_To_Right':
            current = self.head
            while current is not None:
                print(current.data, end=' ')
                current = current.next
            print()
        else:
            current = self.last_node
            while current is not None:
                print(current.data, end=' ')
                current = current.previous
            print()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    L = DoublyLinkedList()
    L.append(1)
    L.append(2)
    L.append(3)
    L.append(4)
    L.display('Left_To_Right')
    L.display('Right_To_Left')
```

This works fine when I copy and paste it into my IDE. However, when I type the same, I get attribute errors. How do I resolve this?

Comment: "when I type the same" The same what? Type it where? "I get attribute errors" What errors? Which line of code is triggering the error? We can't read your mind. Show us.

Comment: I pasted this in PyCharm, and ran it: no errors. Please provide details.

Comment: @Paul H,  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Zulka/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Exercise.py", line 51, in <module>
    L.append(2)
  File "C:/Users/Zulka/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Exercise.py", line 28, in append
    self.last_node.next = node.data
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: @ZulkarnainJibril please edit to the question to contain that information. It's very difficult to read as an unformatted comment

Comment: @PaulH, the same code as I pasted directly into the PyCharm IDE. I don't know where my error really is but I still get AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'. However, if I do not include the __init__() dunder method and just use only class attributes by initializing data = 0, next = None, the code works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including the error message in the question itself, as well as minimal code; for example, the code never gets to `display`, so it's probably irrelevant to the problem. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Also, please write a more descriptive title. The problem is not that you can't run the code, it's that the code raises an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the blank line in `append` as well as the blank line between `__init__` and `append`.  The reader works slightly different when reading a file or an IDE rather than when the user is typing.

The read-eval-print loop in Python interprets blank lines differently than reading from a file.  If the REPL can reasonably interpret the blank line as "end of user input", it will.

Comment: Good catch. I think the lesson here is: Don't copy-paste entire files into the Python REPL.